# Java based Database Connection Pool library for multiple database users

Tags: java, database, connection, pool

Our Java application (web application that runs on Jetty 7.5.4) uses an underlying database. There are multiple databases users and the Java part needs to access the DB using those database users. Am wondering if there is a database connection pool library that lets us access the DB with multiple database users. I know there are a bunch of dbcp libraries that lets us use with single database user, but am unable to find any library that supports multiple database users.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks,
Pram.

Comment: I believe any database is able support multiple users but with different  capacities.

Comment: Mawia, thanks for responding. I am trying to find a _database connection pool library_ that supports multiple database users. I get a feeling that you misunderstood my question because said "any database supports multiple users". Am I right?

Comment: You can configure multiple datasources, each of which connects to the database as a different user.

Comment: I have the same question as @prams and understand multiple data sources.  However, I have an undefined number of users and they may grow, so I'd like the connection pool to support this because I cannot define a datasource for every user... or can I?  Dynamically?

Comment: I'm looking for exactly the same thing. We have a multi-tennant web app and each user connects to the database using their own creditendials to enforce database level role based security. There is no other way in our use case. We have found a situation where being able to use connection pooling with these users would help performance but as of yet can't find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat DBCP definitely supports multiple users ([source code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/modules/jdbc-pool/src/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSourceProxy.java)). I'm not exactly sure how to configure it, but it has implemented `DataSource.getConnection(username, password)`, which is the key feature needed.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ngreen's comment above, you also need to set AlternateUsernameAllowed to true in your data source properties, however you still need to set a username / password on the properties as this is used when the pool is created.

```
/**
 * Returns true if the call {@link DataSource#getConnection(String, String) getConnection(username,password)} is
 * allowed. This is used for when the pool is used by an application accessing multiple schemas.
 * There is a performance impact turning this option on.
 * @return true if {@link DataSource#getConnection(String, String) getConnection(username,password)} is honored, false if it is ignored.
 */
public boolean isAlternateUsernameAllowed();
```